# Tofu and chalkiness

Tags: tofu

I just found out that I have new dietary restrictions. In an effort to get more protein I have begun experimenting with tofu. The problem I am having is when I make tofu " yogurt" or add tofu to my protein shakes I get this chalky or dry feeling on my mouth. It's really bad and not something I think I can just get used to. I am using tofu that comes in little cartons from Costco. Could it be the tofu I'm using or is this just what happens when tofu is made into a more liquid food? Any help would be awesome! Thanks, Lori

Comment: Does it come in different varieties, like firm and silken?

Answer (score 3):

Toufu comes with many different textures. There's dried toufu, which has a meaty texture (and can be substituted in meat dishes), regular toufu, which sounds like what you're using, and soft toufu, which is what you want to be using. It might also be called silky/silken toufu, depending on where you'd buy them and using Japanese toufu is also fine.

The texture should be a bit like custard tart, even softer (In fact they break very easily, you will not be able to pick them up with say like chopsticks). And yes, they are used in desserts all the time.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party here... Try soaking your tofu in hot water for a few minutes, it helps with chalkiness. Good luck!